# Error while installing cassandra in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, apt-get

I am fallowing this tutorial; to install Cassandra on my Ubuntu Server: http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/960-install-nosql-cassandra-db-in-ubuntu-via-ppa-repository

Here is the command that is causing me some problems:

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cassandra

Here is the error message:

Errors were encountered while processing:
 cassandra
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what's breaking there, but you'll want to use the more up to date instructions here:

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DebianPackaging

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it seems to stem from not having /both/ gpg keys imported (the tutorial you link, and the one I tried to use as well, says to replace the key with the one thrown as an error - you seem to need both)